# Deseralize a JSON ( containing HashMap ) returned from Server

Tags: java, json, gwt

I am using gwt client . I need to parse/de-serialize a JSON ( contains Map ) returned from the server. Sample JSON :-

```
APPLICATIONSMAP: {

*
  -
  0: {
      o name: "App 1"
      o id: 0
  }
*
  -
  1: {
      o name: "App 2"
      o id: 1
  }
*
  -
  2: {
      o name: "App 3"
      o id: 2
  }
```

How do I de-serialize the json back to Java HashMap ?

Thanks,
Sachin

Comment: Have you use Google GSon? http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do is the right way to do things, but if you really want to deserialize from a JSON, you could use Jackson:

http://jackson.codehaus.org/

Comment: I have a GWT client and Spring MVC applications. GWT app makes HTTP requests to SPRING MVC and gets the data as JSON Response.I need to parse JSON String to create a HashMap. Hope this helps. I can not use Jackson in GWT client as GWT will not be able to convert jackson classes to javascript code.

Comment: Why would you want to convert JSON to javascript code through a Java JSON processor? JSON can be read in Javascript without any problem. There is something unclear, here, I think.

Comment: I am using Google web toolkit (GWT) to create the GUI and also to process the JSON. GWT allows you to write code in Java. GWT compiler compiles/converts Java Code into Javascript/Html. Hence the need to parse JSON in Java.

Comment: I think I get it, now. What you need to do is generate Java objects from your JSON data, and then GWT can convert them into Javascript. So the solution I suggested, using a Java JSON parser, like Jackson, could be definitivly helpful to create the Java objects. But Chris Lercher's solution below is probably better.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [JavaScript Overlay Types](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay.html), e.g. like this:

```
public class OverlayExample implements EntryPoint {

    public static final class MyJsMap extends JavaScriptObject {

        protected MyJsMap() {}

        public native Object get(Object key) /*-{
            return this[key];
        }-*/;

        public native void put(Object key, Object val) /*-{
            this[key] = val;
        }-*/;
    }

    public void onModuleLoad() {

        final String text = "[{ 1 : 'x', 2 : 'y' }]";
        final MyJsMap map = asJsMap(text);
        System.out.println(map.get("1"));
    }

    private static native MyJsMap asJsMap(final String str) /*-{
        return eval(str)[0];
    }-*/;
}
```

Ok, it's not exactly a `java.util.Map`, but if you need that, you could improve `MyJsMap` to implement the `java.util.Map` interface.

Or - if you need a real `java.util.HashMap` - you could iterate over all values and copy them to a `HashMap`. In the latter case, it's probably easier to use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), as recommended by @The Elite Gentleman.

Comment: I will have a look into first option.

Answer (score 0):

If you use gwt as the tag says, then why do you do JSON yourself? GWT has great serialization support.

Comment: I am not sure if I can use GWT serialization without using GWT RPC. If I can, could you please send me the link to understand how it works. We are not using GWT RPC. We have a Spring MVC webapp which returns data as JSON to GWT client.